# Create lazy sequence (stream) with changing state, e.g. Fibonacci numbers?

Tags: elixir

Question: is it possible to create an Elixir `Stream` that keeps some kind of state internally that changes with each call? How would code look that does it?

I was delighted to see Elixir 0.10.2 having `Stream`s in addition to the normal `Enum` module. While there is documentation on how to use `Stream`s there's little to no documentation nor globally searchable documents that describe how to create them. Reading the source code for the `Stream` module is not very enlightening. I've also studied [Lazily concatenate an enumerable of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341466/lazily-concatenate-an-enumerable-of-lists) and its answer, and while very interesting it doesn't touch on changing state either.

Think of generating Fibonacci numbers where you need to remember the previous two values. Or think of [Clojure's lazy sequence for prime numbers](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib/blob/78ee9b3e64c5ac6082fb223fc79292175e8e4f0c/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/lazy_seqs.clj#L66).

My problems with understanding whether or not this is possible in the first place are:

1. The record's `enumerable` element is only set by some examples, and always to an existing, fixed list. The examples that deal with infinite sequences don't touch `enumerable` at all (e.g. `iterate` or `repeat`).
2. The function provided with `fun` is supposed to return another function, not a new `Stream.Lazy` record which, as far as I can tell, is the big difference to Clojure's lazy sequences where you return a new sequence with `lazy-seq`.
3. How the accumulator `acc` is used is still somewhat beyond me. It looks like the `fun` doesn't modify it itself; instead some outer function calling the `fun` does.

Hence my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Stream.unfold/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/Stream.html#unfold/2) lets you generate a sequence of values while maintaining an "accumulator" (state).

I just built a lazy Fibonacci sequence function using it here: https://github.com/seven1m/30-days-of-elixir/blob/master/24-stream.exs#L31-33

Comment: Seems this is a new function in Elixir 0.12.0. Nice that they're adding this as well.

Answer (score 1):

I just played around the stream. I might be missing the point, but for maintaining the state, exactor (gen_server) could be used?

https://github.com/sasa1977/exactor

Definition

```
defmodule Sample do
  use ExActor

  defcall next(x), state: state, do: reply(state + x, x)

  def fib(n) do
    {:ok, act} = Sample.start(1)
    Stream.iterate(0, fn(x) -> Sample.next(act, x) end) |> Enum.take(n)
  end
end
```

Run

```
iex(3)> Sample.fib(5) 
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
iex(4)> Sample.fib(10)
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

Comment: I'll definitely take a look at it. Thanks for the pointer. I'll leave the question open though, as your post doesn't exactly answer it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in lazy streams, but here's my attempt: https://gist.github.com/sasa1977/6699577

Note however, that in this example, state is public, rather than internal, so I don't know if this is what you're looking for.

The solution relies first on creating a record (in this case private), and exposing a function which can move the record to the next state:

```
fib0 = Fibonacci.new
fib1 = Fibonacci.next(fib0)
fib2 = Fibonacci.next(fib1)
fib3 = Fibonacci.next(fib2)
IO.inspect fib3
```

Each `fibx` contains the full state. In this case, I'm keeping the current number, plus the previously two generated numbers.

Based on this, I can now use [`Stream.iterate`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/Stream.html#iterate/2) to make an endless lazy collection:

```
Fibonacci.lazy
|> Enum.take(5)
|> IO.inspect
```

Since it is based on `Fibonacci.next`, each generated element is a record, rather than a value. You can use `Fibonacci.value` to extract value from each element.

A more complex manipulations can also be performed:

```
Fibonacci.lazy
|> Stream.drop(3)                                           # drop first three
|> Enum.first                                               # take the first
|> Fibonacci.lazy                                           # start lazy from it
|> Stream.filter(&(rem(Fibonacci.value(&1), 2) == 1))       # take only odd values
|> Stream.map(&(Fibonacci.value(&1)))                       # extract values from it
|> Enum.take(10)                                            # take first 10
|> IO.inspect                                               # print it
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely give this a spin. The state being public is more or less a matter of taste and not important to me.